# Can't install a gem for Solargraph

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install the gem of solargraph to use it on VS Code. So I install Ruby with the devkit, I install the MSYS2. But when I want to install the gem of solargraph, so I write in the terminal : `gem install solargraph --no-doc`. But I have a error code:

```
C:\Users\antoi>gem install solargraph --no-doc
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing solargraph:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: D:/Applications et jeux/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.4/ext/jaro_winkler
D:/Applications\ et\ jeux/Ruby26/bin/ruby.exe -I D:/Applications\ et\ jeux/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210803-3268-1xf290n.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: D:/Applications et jeux/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.4/ext/jaro_winkler
make "DESTDIR=" clean
Makefile:270: *** motifs de cible multiples. Arrêt.

current directory: D:/Applications et jeux/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.4/ext/jaro_winkler
make "DESTDIR="
Makefile:270: *** motifs de cible multiples. Arrêt.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Applications et jeux/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.4 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Applications et jeux/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.6.0/jaro_winkler-1.5.4/gem_make.out
```

I restart my terminal, I delete and reinstall all files of Ruby, but it doesn't work...
So if someone what is the problem, I'll take it.

Comment: how did you install your version of ruby on that windows system?  did you follow anything like: https://stackify.com/install-ruby-on-windows-everything-you-need-to-get-going/

Comment: The error you're seeing is native code compilation failing.  This is typically a problem on windows, as most ruby projects are targeted to and developed on unix-like systems.

I don't have a direct solution for this on windows (I don't use it for programming), but I'd suggest switching to linux, or running linux in a VM or trying WSL2.

If you need to use Windows, you'll need to look at the compilation log and figure out how to get the missing headers, failed linkages to libraries that may not exist on windows.  A bit too much, for my tastes.

Good luck!